# Extract data from HTML to Dictionnary

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I want extract data from a web page, but in an organized way.
That is, I want the text to be stored in a dictionary whose keys are the names of the classes and the value is a list that contains the different texts of their classes.
Is this possible ? I tried with Selinum and BeautifulSoup, but I did not find the solution!
Do you have any advice for me ?

exalmple :

```
<div class="a1">
    ...
    <H1 class="title">1_title<H1>
    ...
        <a class="text">this is a text 1<a>
    ...
    <a class="text">this is a text 2<a>
    <H2 class="title">2_title<H2>
    ...
        <p class="note"> this is a note<p>
<div>
```

output:

```
dict = {
    "title" : ["1_title", "2_title"]
    "text"  : ["this is a text 1", "this is a text 2"]
    "note"  : ["this is a note"]
}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Any code example will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

There are may ways to do that but best practice is to use either [css](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors) or [xpath](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath) selectors.

In python popular package for this is either `beautifulsoup4` or `parsel`.
Here's code example using `parsel` package and `xpath` selectors:

```py
from parsel import Selector

body = """
<div class="a1">
    <h1 class="title">1_title</h1>
    <a class="text">this is a text 1</a>
    <a class="text">this is a text 2</a>
    <h2 class="title">2_title</h2>
    <p class="note"> this is a note</p>
</div>
"""

selector = Selector(body)
result = {
    "title": selector.xpath('//*[self::h1 or self::h2]/text()').extract(),
    "text": selector.xpath('//a/text()').extract(),
    "note": selector.xpath('//p/text()').extract(),
}

print(result)
```

Which results in:

```
{'title': ['1_title', '2_title'], 'text': ['this is a text 1', 'this is a text 2'], 'note': [' this is a note']}
```

Answer (score 0):

Without any external library. The idea is to "look" at the HTML as XML and use built in parser in order to extract the data.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
from collections import defaultdict
body = """
<div class="a1">
    <h1 class="title">1_title</h1>
    <a class="text">this is a text 1</a>
    <a class="text">this is a text 2</a>
    <h2 class="title">2_title</h2>
    <div><a class="xyz">text3</a></div>
    <p class="note"> this is a note!!</p>
    <p>no class</p>
</div>
"""

data = defaultdict(list)
root = ET.fromstring(body)
for e in root.findall('.//*[@class]'):
  data[e.attrib['class']].append(e.text)
for k,v in data.items():
  print(f'{k} -> {v}')
```

output

```
    title -> ['1_title', '2_title']
    text -> ['this is a text 1', 'this is a text 2']
    xyz -> ['text3']
    note -> [' this is a note!!']
```

Answer (score -1):

```
elements=driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*")
d={}
for ele in elements:
    if ele.get_attribute('class'):
        d[ele.get_attribute('class')]=ele.text
print(d)
```

Comment: This is a very low quality answer, without any explanation. Please try to explain why your solution should work.

Comment: Please add the required imports to make this solution work. This looks like a promising solution, you can make it a good answer with some more edits.